# Taking the limit of $\infty - \infty.$ How can I arrange it to work?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( xe^{1/x}-x \right)$$

I don't know how I can solve this. Any help?

Comment: What theorems do you have about limits ? Do you know Taylor expansion ?

Comment: Hint: Rewrite as $\frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{1/x}$ (factor out $x,$ then move the $x$ to the denominator) and then consider the variable change $u = 1/x$ (with $u \rightarrow 0^{+}.)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite it as $$\lim_{x\to\infty} xe^{1/x}-x =\lim_{x\to\infty}  \frac{e^{1/x}-1}{x^{-1}}$$ and use L'Hospital's rule. After one application of L'Hospital's rule you should be able to evaluate the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Thats what I needed. A way touse that rule

Comment: You are welcome, good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Write it as:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{1/x}-1}{1/x} = \lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{e^h-1}{h}$$

Comment: Where did h come from

Comment: It's a change of variable. He just let $h=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) =\lim_{h\to 0^+} f(1/h)$ for any $f$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
Use the Taylor series for $e^x$: $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^4)$.

Comment: We haven't learned taylor expansion yet. This is Calc I and we just started integrals